# How can I filter data in Neo4j?

Tags: neo4j

In neo4j, i want to filter and collect data by foreach  statement.
Example
My user case with mysql.
    `users = User ->findAll();
    data = array();
    foreach(users as user){
    profile = Profile:findBy(user);
    if(user.age > 20 and profile.company is empty)
    data[] = user;
    }
    return data`

thank

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Cypher, this is roughly equivalent to your code:

```
MATCH (u:User)-[:HAS_PROFILE]->(p:Profile)
WHERE u.age > 20 AND (p.company IS NULL OR p.company = "")
RETURN u;
```

This query assumes you have nodes labelled `User` (with at least an `age` property) and `Profile` (with a `company` property that is either optional or that may contain an empty string), connected by `HAS_PROFILE` relationships.

Comment: hi @cybersam, thank for your sharding. it work for me! thank you